# where are the mvc 2 files saved to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

just installed asp.net mvc 2, where are the new .dll's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the Global Assembly Cache on your machine? (C:\WINDOWS\assembly or whatever your system root is)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's in the [Global Assembly Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies` or the equivalent on your machine.

But may I ask why you need it?

If you're trying to reference it in a Visual Studio project, you can add a reference to it the normal way; right-click on project, then add reference, search under `.NET` tab.

If you need to place it in the bin of a deployed project, you can set the property `Copy Local` of the `System.Web.Mvc` reference under the `Reference` folder under the project. This way, everytime you build/publish the project/solution, `System.Web.Mvc` will also be placed in the bin folder.

Comment: i like to reference from my /lib folder, easier for deploying etc.